# React initial state from props and any updates to local state should reflect in parent

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

What is the correct way to handle the case with React Hooks, where a child's state is set from parent prop, but any changes to the child should update the parent.  The parent prop can keep changing.
For example,

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
    const [container, setContainer] = useState({ name: 'hello'});
    
   //some other user action causes container to change
   //which should reflect in the child.  Any subsequent update to child's input field 
   //should update parent again.
    onChange = (payload) => {
        container.name = payload.name
    }
    return (
        <ChildComponent container={container} dispatch={onChange} />
    );
    
};

const ChildComponent = (props) => {
    const { container, dispatch } = props;
    const [name, setName] = useState(container.name);
    
    useEffect(()=>{
        const payload = { name };
        dispatch(payload);
    },[name]);
    return (
        <input value={name} onChange= {(e)=>setName(e.target.value)} />
    );
};
```

Would this not cause an infinite loop?